# How to get table name from current query in php or postgresql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, postgresql, pdo

is it possible to get table name from current query using pdo php or normal sql in postgresql?

In pdo php a function exists like `PDOStatement::getColumnMeta` but this function doesn't work well, because it return name of alias in query and when I use notation like

```
SELECT configuration.id AS other_name
FROM   configuration.mytable AS other_table_name
INNER JOIN  configuration.some_table AS other_some_table_name
ON other_table_name.id = other_some_table_name.id
```

it back strange values. I`m interested to get base name of table without aliases. Anybody know better way to get table name of actual query?

**Update for Elvis Ciotii answer**

Here is sql:

```
    SELECT        *
    FROM           configuration.applications
    WHERE        url=:url
```

Here is result

```
      Array
            (
                [pgsql:oid] => 23
                [native_type] => int4
                [name] => id
                [len] => 4
                [precision] => -1
                [pdo_type] => 1
            )
```

in documentation php.net function PDOStatement::getColumnMeta() return an associative array containing the following values representing the metadata for a single column:

native_type, driver:decl_type, flags, name, table, len, precision, pdo_type

Where is in my result flags and table key??

I need this value because i`m working at my little framework where i want implements to model class special returnig function with resulting executed queries. I was thinking if i cant get this value from pdo i cant get this value in normal query. etc. SHOW TABLES or something like this.

Comment: A query builder like Zend_Db_Select stores this information if PDO doesn't make it available.

Comment: And if your query refers to more than one table, which is true for any non-trivial query (unions, joins, subqueries etc.) what do you expect to get?

Comment: but in query above i dont use any join only SELECT .... FROM configuration.application (schema.table)

Answer (score 0):

```
$dbconn = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname='dbname' user='username' password='password' ")
or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());
$query = "SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'public' ORDER BY table_name";


$result = pg_query($dbconn,$query) or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());

$tablesRes = pg_fetch_all($result);
$tableArray = array_column($tablesRes, 'table_name');
foreach ($tableArray as $tables){
//Do your logic here
}
```